# how do you echo text from a file using batch?

Tags: batch-file

okay, so I'm trying to make a batch file that just echos the text inside a file called "test.txt" and my code is

```
@echo off
cls
(
echo %0%
echo %1%
echo %2%
echo %3%
echo %4%
echo %5%
echo %6%
echo %7%
echo %8%
echo %9%
echo %10%
echo %11%
echo %12%
echo %13%
echo %14%
echo %15%
echo %16%
) <test.txt
pause >nul
```

but for some very strange reason I couldn't find any answers for anywhere, my output is

```
ECHO is off.    
ECHO is off.    
ECHO is off.    
ECHO is off.    
ECHO is off.    
ECHO is off.    
ECHO is off.    
ECHO is off.    
0    
1    
2    
3    
4    
5    
6
```

and I really don't understand why.

Comment: You probably haven't set those variables. I also recommend starting a variable with a letter, because starting a variable with numbers won't always work.

Comment: There are no variables called %0%, %1% etc. You seem to be confusing environment variables with command-line argument parameters. At the command prompt, read all of the relevant help information by typing `CALL /?` and `FOR /?` (pay particular attention to FOR /F).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **echo** the text that's inside your `test.txt` file, then you need to add this line to your batch file as already said by @[Blorgbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369/blorgbeard).

```
type C:\..\test.txt
@pause
```

Adding this line to your batch file will display the text/contents of a file in the command prompt window.

Answer (score 1):

With this batch file you can echo your `test.txt` file :

```
@echo off
Set "MyFile=test.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%MyFile%"') Do (
echo %%a )
pause
```

Comment: You don't need your handling for blank lines, as FOR /F will never give you empty lines

Comment: @jeb Thank you for your remark and i edit my answer due to your comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Copy the numbers below into test.txt on your desktop.

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
.
```

Now copy and paste the code below into print.bat on your desktop.

```
@ECHO OFF
type "%UserProfile%\Desktop\test.txt"
@pause
```

now run print.bat

REM:: Big thanks to Rakitić,  Blorgbeard & Hackoo.